# Is there better way to implement OAuth security in swagger-tools API?

Tags: node.js, oauth, swagger, swagger-tools

I prepared Swagger 2.0 definition for my API implemented on node.js/connect. I added security definitions:

```
securityDefinitions:
  BasicAuth:
    type: basic
  OAuth2:
    type: oauth2
    flow: accessCode
    authorizationUrl: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
    tokenUrl: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
    scopes:
      scope1: my scope 1
      scope2: my scope 2
```

and the API:

```
  /myAPI:
    post:
      [...]
      security:
        - BasicAuth: []
        - OAuth2: [scope1]
```

Thus API is secured either by Basic HTTP Auth or by OAuth2 (actually bearer token), requiring scope 'scope1'.
Now the implementation.
I use swagger-tools to generate my API stub:

java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l nodejs-server -i my.yaml -o out

As far as I know generated swagger-tools code doesn't do anything about security, so I added custom code for that:

```
[...]
let secoptions = {
  'BasicAuth': function( req, securityDefinition, scopes, callback) {
    basicAuth( req, callback);
  },
  'OAuth2': function( req, securityDefinition, scopes, callback) {
    oAuth2( req, scopes, callback);
  }
}
app.use( middleware.swaggerSecurity( secoptions));
[...other swagger-tools generated init code...]
```

I use passport-http BasicStrategy for basicAuth processing.
I use passport-http-bearer Strategy with openid-client for oAuth2 bearer token processing.
And that works, however:

1. I'm just wondering if I'm using correct tools/libraries here?
2. Does swagger-tools really does nothing about security defined in Swagger file?
3. There is completely no automatic scope processing/verifying - I have to manually check in oAuth2 function if the token provided (as bearer) contains scopes required by the API Swagger definition.
   Is that correct way to do that or maybe there some hidden option or something to automatically verify scopes?